# How to decide whether or not use Perl CGI vs regular HTML output

Tags: perl, cgi

I've discovered that CGI is no longer recommended when it comes to creating HTML pages, but my search for answers as to where the use of [`CGI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI) is appropriate has caused more confusion than answers.

I apologise if my question is basic, but I'm hoping that an answer to my question will help to clarify some things.

I'm being told not to create a form like this:

```
sub output_form {
    my ($q) = @_;


    print $q->start_form(
        -name => 'main',
        -method => 'POST',
    );

    print $q->start_table;

    print $q->Tr(
      $q->td('Update#:'),
      $q->td(
        $q->textfield(-name => "update_num", -size => 02)
      )
    );

    print $q->Tr(
      $q->td('Date:'),
      $q->td(
        $q->textfield(-name => "date",-id => "datepicker")
      )
    );

    print $q->Tr(
      $q->td('Location:'),
      $q->td(
        $q->textfield(-name => "location", -size => 50)
      )
    );

    print $q->Tr(
      $q->td('Queue:'),
      $q->td(
        $q->textfield(-name => "queue", -size => 50)
      )
    );

    print $q->Tr(
      $q->td('ETO:'),
      $q->td(
        $q->textfield(-name => "eto", -size => 50)
      )
    );

    print $q->Tr(
      $q->td('CAD#:'),
      $q->td(
        $q->textfield(-name => "cad", -size => 50)
      )
    );

    print $q->Tr(
      $q->td('Remarks:'),
      $q->td(
        $q->textfield(-name => "remarks", -size => 50)
    )
```

But if I create such a form using a regular HTML page, will I be able to interact with user input from a Perl script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update

I've looked at your question again, and it seems like you've become so entrenched in what `CGI` offers that you've got yourself lost

> But if create such a form using a regular HTML page, will I be able to interact with user input from a Perl script?

Whatever your program does, and however it does it, it ***must*** send an ordinary HTML page back to the browser that made the original request. There is nothing magical about the various `start_form`, `start_table`, `Tr`, `td` etc. functions that `CGI` makes available: it is supposed to be a more convenient way of generating HTML using Perl syntax

Generating HTML is nothing to do with the CGI protocol, and many people felt that it was inappropriate to include that sort of functionality in a module called `CGI`. That lead to things such as [`HTML::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Tiny), which provides HTML construction functions similar to `CGI`

Other functions grew to provide ***just*** support for the CGI protocol, such as [`CGI::Minimal`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Minimal)

There are many more examples of the separate implementation of both aspects of the original `CGI.pm`, but you are concerned about whether you can interact with a use via HTTP

Once again, there is *nothing special* about the functions that `CGI.pm` makes available. You should run an old CGI program from the command line to see that it just generates the string of HTML that you have prescribed in your calls, and you could have created that in any way that was convenient

Once the HTML has been built and sent to the client, it makes no difference *how* the message was built. The page will be displayed on the browser and it will offer the user the chance to request more information

I hope that's clearer for you?

---

Take a look at [`CGI::Alternatives`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eleejo/CGI-Alternatives-0.14/lib/CGI/Alternatives.pm) for options other than CGI

But you're talking about constructing HTML, which is nothing to do with CGI, and one of the main criticisms of the module was that it wrapped too much functionality into a single box

You should focus on using a template package to build your HTML, and one of the most popular is [`Template::Toolkit`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eabw/Template-Toolkit-2.26/lib/Template.pm)

You probably have additional CSS styling and JavaScript intelligence, which should be linked from your HTML as separate files

Comment: As you mentioned I've totally confused myself trying to understand what technology to use to properly implement what I'm trying to do. Let me explain what this form is trying to achieve maybe you can guide me better. the form I've posted in my question is the second page of my mini application, first page is like a mini login page where I asks the user to input their name and last name. 2nd page is the form and the 3rd page is just displaying and emailing of the results(and the results are input from 1st and 2nd page)

Comment: @Allen: I think it may be useful for you to look through an HTTP tutorial. The computer where someone is running a browser (Firefox, Chrome etc: the client) generates requests, and is completely separate from the system that generates the HTML response (the server). The simplest request is someone typing in a URL to their browser's address field. The URL dictates what HTML the server returns. Filling in a form on the browser produces a more complex URL, with a different result when they press **Send**. You should see what Google can find for "HTTP tutorial", and Wikipedia is usually good.

Comment: Actually CGI.pm does not offer those HTML generation functions any more. After CGI was removed from the core, those got taken out of CGI.pm and moved into [CGI::HTML::Functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI/HTML/Functions.pod).

Comment: @Allen: There is normally no connection between one request from a client and the next. By the time the browser sends the second page, the data entered into the first has been forgotten. The solution is to use cookies, which is a way of storing data so that it persists across HTTP transactions. You can either store all the information in a database on the server, and keep only a session ID (a database key) as a cookie, or if the data isn't sensitive then you can store all of it as cookies.

Answer (score 1):

For a browser to present an HTML page to a user, the web sever has to return an HTTP response that includes the required HTML in the body. Sometimes that HTML is returned from a static file and sometimes it is generated by some server-side application.

The browser doesn't care (and, indeed, is unlikely to know) how that HTML is generated. All it knows is that it has received an HTTP response with a Content-Type of text/html and a body consisting of HTML which it needs to parse and render.

So you have a couple of options. You can write a static HTML file that contains your form. Or you can write a Perl program that generates it. Either of these options makes no difference to the browser. You have chosen to write a Perl program. There are various technologies that you can use to implement this. I wouldn't recommend CGI these days (see [CGI:Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for some suggestions) but let's assume that we're going with that.

(It's also worth pointing out here that CGI - the protocol - is not the same thing as CGI.pm the library that is often used to write Perl programs that run under the protocol. You don't need to use CGI.pm to write a CGI program.)

CGI.pm used to include helper functions for generating HTML. These are now deprecated and have been moved to a separate module. There are many reasons for their deprecation. The most obvious one is probably that on many projects, the people designing and implementing the front-end of the site are different people to the ones writing the back-end code. If a front-end developer already needs to know HTML, CSS and Javascript, it's slightly unfair to expect them to know Perl as as - which they would need in order to edit the web pages using the HTML generation functions. Even in a situation where I am the only person working on a site, I find that enforcing a strict separation between the front- and back-end technologies helps to keep the code cleaner.

So I really wouldn't recommend using those functions. No-one would, as far as I can see. Instead. I would use a templating system. In particular, I'd use the [Template Toolkit](http://tt2.org/) (that's a personal preference, but [I'm slightly biased](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004767.do)).

With a templating engine, you can put all of your HTML code in a completely separate file which your front-end team can own and edit in whatever way they choose. Then, when your back-end code needs to display the HTML page, it can use template-processing functions to do that. A (very!) simple example might look like this:

In template.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Template;
use CGI qw[header param]; # Only use two functions from CGI.pm

print header;

my $tt = Template->new;

if (my $name = param('name')) {
  $tt->process('output.tt', { name => $name })
    or die $tt->error;
} else {
  $tt->process('form.tt')
    or die $tt->error;
}
```

`form.tt` would look like this:

```
<html>
  <head><title>What's your name?</title></head>
  <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Enter name: <input name="name" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And `output.tt` would look like this:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Welcome [% name %]</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello [% name %]</h1>
    <p>Pleased to meet you.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The fall of CGI.pm came from two directions. The HTML-building methods were always an ugly duckling, with some form of template being preferred. At the other side, the methods that handled interaction with the client (CGI) were superseded first by mod_perl (which has its own library for this sort of thing), and later by frameworks like Dancer and Mojolicious.

Those frameworks also incorporate templates. There's very little reason to learn the old style CGI anymore, unless you're maintaining old code. There's also plenty of debate between the Dancer and Mojo camps; I'd suggest picking one, learning it on one project, and then take up the other on another project.

Comment: All other things cast aside, I will always prefer Mojolicious. But it is rare that the time to learn Mojo can be accommodated in the development of a new web page.For something like an ***Under Construction*** page I will always go for a simple CGI script. And until [PSGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/PSGI) is more than just documentation I am sure that many others will agree with me.

Comment: Given that PSGI is a specification, it's hard to see how it can ever become more than documentation :-) [Plack](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack) is the toolkit for writing PSGI-compliant apps (but I'm sure you already know that).